# Architecture for XMPP-based chat service using web sockets

Tags: sockets, node.js, websocket

Let's say I want to create a web and web socket-based chat service. And let's also say that I want multiple, discrete chat rooms.

I need this to scale, so, I'm thinking to use XMPP so that I can transparently use multiple servers. Is the architecture shown in the diagram what I would need?

[image]

And, would I even need NodeJS?

Answer (score 2):

How about a node.js load balancer and multiple node.js servers behind it.

use something like redis to store the data and handle message passing. See this [article](http://devblog.bu.mp/how-we-use-redis-at-bump)

Then each client lives on a node.js server, you don't care which.

Each message get's handled by a node.js server (you don't care which).

Every message gets send into redis by the node.js server that handles that incoming message.

Then each node.js server picks it up and pushes it to all clients connected to that server and that chat room.

You'll need a bit of black magic to pipe messages from the single socket.io connection on your load balancer into tcp sockets of your multiple node.js servers.

Comment: Now, let's say that I want multiple, discrete chat rooms. How does this change your architecture?

Comment: @ChadJohnson it doesn't need to change. handle multiple rooms over one socket.io connection isn't hard. The user object just gets a `room: Array` key/value attached to it. If you mean multiple chat rooms as in using multiple socket.io connection then we need less piping black magic and can have each server handle its own websocket connection.

Comment: Okay. "Every message gets send into redis and each node.js server picks it up and pushes it to all clients" is what I am thinking would need to change.

Comment: @ChadJohnson re-worded slightly. Yes they don't push to all clients they only push to the clients "subscribed" to said room. You just filter the client list. That's a trivial extension. Having multiple independant web chat servers on different sockets requires a real architecture change.

Comment: @Raynos can you link to another similar article?  Are you referring to some pubsub features of redis?